# How can I trigger multiple hover actions/events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I have 5 boxes here, as I hover from one end to another the boxes change color, the transition delay is 6s hence the animations are slow.

How can I trigger multiple hover events,

that is when I move the mouse over a div, it should trigger its hover event.

Example: when I move mouse from left to right, all the divs' hover events should run.

In my code the first hover effect is triggered, then it waits the event to end, then starts the next hover effect on some other div which is just under the pointer.

```css
.box{
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: .6s 0s;
  text-align:center;
}

#box-1:hover{background-color: #C8F608;}
#box-2:hover{background-color: #23DC07;}
#box-3:hover{background-color: #07D7D7;}
#box-4:hover{background-color: #076BD7;}
#box-5:hover{background-color: #1307D7;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box" id="box-1">bx1</div>
  <div class="box" id="box-2">bx2</div>
  <div class="box" id="box-3">bx3</div>
  <div class="box" id="box-4">bx4</div>
  <div class="box" id="box-5">bx5</div>
</div>
```

here's my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/biwin007/LYT8J/)

thank you for any help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `background-color` indicated in `:hover` no longer applies when you leave the element. So the element will go back to its unhovered state. You cannot prevent this from happening when depending solely on `:hover`.

Instead, you can add a class on hover, so that the effect remains.

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/LYT8J/3/

**CSS**

```
#box-1:hover, #box-1.hovered {background-color: #C8F608;}
#box-2:hover, #box-2.hovered {background-color: #23DC07;}
#box-3:hover, #box-3.hovered {background-color: #07D7D7;}
#box-4:hover, #box-4.hovered {background-color: #076BD7;}
#box-5:hover, #box-5.hovered {background-color: #1307D7;}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('.box').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('hovered');
});
$('.container').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).find('.hovered').removeClass('hovered');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You want all of your `div` tags to trigger the hover effect when hovering over one, correct?

If that is the case you can use `jQuery` to solve this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div[id^='box-']").mouseenter(function() {
    $("#box-1").css("background-color", "#C8F608");
    $("#box-2").css("background-color", "#23DC07");
    $("#box-3").css("background-color", "#07D7D7");
    $("#box-4").css("background-color", "#076BD7");
    $("#box-5").css("background-color", "#1307D7");
  });

  $("div[id^='box-']").mouseleave(function() {
    $("#box-1").css("background-color", "#EEEEEE");
    $("#box-2").css("background-color", "#EEEEEE");
    $("#box-3").css("background-color", "#EEEEEE");
    $("#box-4").css("background-color", "#EEEEEE");
    $("#box-5").css("background-color", "#EEEEEE");
  });
});
```

This should do what you want. When you enter any `div` tag with `id` that begins with `box-` it will trigger this `mouseenter` event to change the `background-color` of each `div` individually. The `mouseleave` event will restore the background-color to it's original `background-color`. You didn't list the original color so I just said `#EEEEEE` for a light gray color.